# Failed building wheel for pyzmq. could not build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, cookiecutter

`could not build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.`

Things I found on internet didn't help (such as `pip install pyzmq==23.2.1`)

[image]

To reproduce: follow ipywidgets > custom widget tutorial project build steps:
(happens when you run `python -m pip install -e .`)
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Custom.html